# how to avoid java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space

Tags: java, webserver

I am often getting this error when I restart my resin web server. How to avoid this error.

```
11:01:55.679] {resin-12} WebApp[production/webapp/default/app] fail
[15-11-24 11:01:55.681] {resin-95} java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800) 
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
```

Comment: google for java heap size, -Xms, -Xmx

Answer (score 1):

Try to increase value of variables
-Xms, -Xmx, -XX:PermSize, -XX:MaxPermSize in your apache configuration.

E.g. `-Xms1024m -Xmx2048m -XX:PermSize=1024M -XX:MaxPermSize=2048M`